# Unterminated <%@ page tag

Tags: jsp

i try to run my jsp page i got an exeption

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /home.jsp (line: 1, column: 2) Unterminated <%@ page tag 
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
```

Code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html"; charset="ISO-8859-1″
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="Servlet.*,java.util.*"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"&gt;
  <html>
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="ISO-8859-1″>
     <title>Insert title here</title>
       </head>
     <body>
       <form name=frm method="post" action="./InsertImage">
      <table>
      <tr><TD ><B>Upload Image</B></TD>
       <td><input type="file" name="Image" size="20″ value=""></TD>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td><input type="submit" height="30″ width="62″> 
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <TD><b>ClickImage</b>
        <%
        GetImage udet = new GetImage();
        Vector V_ids=new Vector();
        V_ids=udet.ImageList();
        for(int i=0;i<V_ids.size();i++)
        {

        String temp[] = new String[2];
        int j=i+1;
        temp=(String[])V_ids.get(i);

         %></TD>
         <td><a target=’_blank’ href=’                                  <%=response.encodeURL("RetrieveImage?Image_id="+temp[0])%>’ onmouseover=’_ScrollStatus(“Click here for view”, 1);’ onmouseout=’_StopScrollStatus();’ onblur=’_StopScrollStatus();’ >
<b><%=temp[1]%></b>
        </a></TD>

         <%

         }

      %></TR>
      </table>

        </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why this  exception occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have syntax error in `<%@ page` directive:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html"; charset="ISO-8859-1″
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="Servlet.*,java.util.*"%>
```

After `contentType="text/html"` you have semicolon`;`. Remove that semicolon, and it should work fine. Also is `Servlet.*` is a correct package name? You also have fancy quote after `charset="ISO-8859-1″`, change this to `charset="ISO-8859-1"` and finally remove `language` attribute, it is redundant.

Comment: Also, the fancy quote closing `charset="ISO-8859-1″` is messing up the syntax highlighting - not sure if that's really a problem though.

Comment: Yes you're right @PaulBellora, I will update my answer to reflect same

Answer (score 0):

Check, if you have used any extra % tags in directive

Comment: The issue with your code seems to be, as it says in the error output, that you have an unterminated <%@ page tag. So you need to close your page tag to fix the issue.